# Getting source of an event in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

Is there any way to get the source of an event? I know event.getSource() however, is there any way to convert it into a string?

For example, if the source is a button, button1, is there anyway to assign the value button1 to a string variable? (I'm dealing with a lot of buttons and so, I can't write if statements)

Comment: What exactly do you want to assign to string? The button text?

Comment: It's been a while, but as I recall, you can make a sublcass of an EventListener specific to your buttons. Then, when you give your button one of these event listeners, you can make a constructor that accepts whatever value you want, to be used when handling an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity:

The [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) method returns the object from which the Event initially occurred. You could use this to get some sort of property from the element, like the text inside a label or the name of a button.

These are Strings, but if you chose to go this route, I would make sure you pick something that is uniform across all components that will be calling that `ActionListerner`.

This is where [`getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29) might come in handy. You can set unique 'identifiers' when components are created, and the access them later.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.setActionCommand("1");

JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.setActionCommand("2");
```

Then you can compare these later using any method you like, or you could do something fancy, like this (because you said you didn't want to use if-else statements):

```
String command = e.getActionCommand();
int i = Integer.parseInt(command);

switch (i) {
    case 1: // do something
        break;
}
```

According to the Java docs:

> Returns the command string associated with this action. This string allows a "modal" component to specify one of several commands, depending on its state. For example, a single button might toggle between "show details" and "hide details". The source object and the event would be the same in each case, but the command string would identify the intended action.

Keep in mind that I think this is best approach only if you are using one `ActionListerner` for lots of components. As another answer pointed out, you could just make unique `ActionListeners` per each button.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass anything you want to an action listener through the constructor, as  DaaaahWhoosh stated in his comment.

```
package com.ggl.fse;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private String buttonText;

    public ButtonActionListener(String buttonText) {
        this.buttonText = buttonText;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The buttonText String will be available in the actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific `ActionListener` for each `JButton`. Try this code:

```
private static String text;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            text = button1.getText();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text is: " + text);
        }
    });

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            text = button2.getText();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text is: " + text);
        }
    });

    frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```